# Jira dashboard organization

Tags: jira, dashboard

I am doing automation on over ten products. In jira I am using Kanban style workflow where there is no sprint and work sits in a Kanban board. I want to make dashboards for the different projects. The first problem I am running into is that I have lots of different breakdowns I would like to look at and I am running out of room on my dashboard. It says I can't use any more gadgets on my dashboard. I would like to make several different dashboards for a project for different categories and I would like to group them together. Then I want to do this across over ten projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jira is not a data visualization tool so don't expect too much out of it, My suggestions is to not overcomplicate, are all this gadgets really that useful?, if yes the simple approach would be to at least organize them using a naming rule, for example Project-Strategic-week-performance.

Maybe a plugin like this one can help you with the organization: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217625/dashboard-folders-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview

But overall try no to force a tool for what it wasn't made for because you are going to need a lot of effort and not getting the best results.